# Retrieve list.items from specific view instead of all items

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, view

I am trying to export items in a sharepoint 2013 powershell script array to be pulled from only a certain custom view on the list. I created a view that shows the "Current Month" - items that were created in the current calendar month only. All previous items remain in the list, but we only wish to see and work with ones entered this month.

I have tried following the below and many variations of it:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134830/powershell-script-to-get-items-only-in-a-particular-view-of-sharepoint-list-libr

```
$list = $web.Lists["testlist"]
$view = $list.Views["Current Month"]
$items = $list.GetItems($view)

#Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
$ListItemCollection = @()

$items.Items | foreach {
```

The below code works fine to get all items in the list and email sent ok.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "https://sharepointsite.com"
$list = $web.Lists["testlist"]

#Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
$ListItemCollection = @()

$list.Items | foreach {
    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject 
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value ($_["Name"] -replace '^\d+;#')
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Reason" -Value $_["Reason"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Example" -Value $_["Example"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Created" -Value $_["Created"]

    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
}

$web.Dispose()

$emailbody = $(cat C:\temp\emailbody.txt) + $ListItemCollection

#Email formatting
$style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
$style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
$style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "</style>"

$SMTPServer = "mail.com"
$EmailFrom = "test@mail.com" 
$EmailTo = "joel@mail.com"
$EmailSubject = "Test Email"

$Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $EmailFrom, $EmailTo
$Message.Subject = $EmailSubject
$Message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$message.Body = $emailbody + ($ListItemCollection | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style | Out-String)
$SMTP = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer)
$SMTP.Send($Message)
```

When I use the code sampled above this it gives the error for each of the 3 add-member lines:
Cannot index into a null array.

Comment: So all the members are having the attribute Example ?? I doubt that.. Please check that and see if that is the specific value to be fetched or not. I cant test it at my end.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your comment. Each item there is the name of a column in the list. Here is what it looks like when emailed: https://snag.gy/0YGinp.jpg (notice the created date for the first one is in April, I dont want this included.

This is what the all items view shows on the live sharepoint site:
https://snag.gy/06gMGZ.jpg

This is what the current view shows on the live sharepoint site:
https://snag.gy/Ym7k8y.jpg

(Ignore the differences of the actual text values, I pasted over the real one as it says something different - live testing and all...)

Comment: I am trying to predict the `$list.Items` because without understanding what is present, it cannot be dealt with. If possible post a sample.

Comment: Hey, Yes I posted this sample for the other answer below: https://pastebin.com/Ts7040AA is that what you were after?

Comment: So, seeing that I can understand the list doesnot have any property called Reason and Example. So $_.Example and $_.Reason is coming as null. Thereby the error

Comment: ok, so what is the fix then? I get the intended result from the script as posted for all items, my question is how to get the results from only a specific view.

Comment: Say you have one property called Name which is resulting properly. So you can do `ExportItem.Name` to get the value of the object. Similarly if you are adding in the arraylist items also, you can do the same. I am unsure if this is what you meant. Else I will try to give more insights.

Comment: If I run the real script I can get all correct results from this. The examples actual values are Who, What, How. See below:
`PS C:\Windows\system32> $exportitem.Who
Paul`
I expect this result since that was the last added to the array. If I run this on the listitemcollection I expect to see all names as below:
`PS C:\Windows\system32> $ListItemCollection.who
Joel
Joel
Paul`
What I want to do though, is run the script I already have working on a specific view of the list which is pre filtered itself by date, so I would then only get results based on that filter if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is what worked:

`$view = $list.Views["Current Month"]
$items = $list.GetItems($view)`

Array to Hold Result - PSObjects

`$ListItemCollection = @()`

Get All List items

`$items | foreach {`

When I use this to get from the whole list/all items, it uses:

Array to Hold Result - PSObjects

`$ListItemCollection = @()`

Get All List items

`$list.Items | foreach {`

Removing the .Items reference from the last line was the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can give us an example of $list.Items ?

What about using foreach ( $item in $list.items ) ?

```
foreach ( $item in $list.Items ) {
    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject 
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $( $item.name -replace '^\d+;#' )
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Reason" -Value $item.reason
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Example" -Value $item.example
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Created" -Value $item.created

   $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
}
```

foreach () {} and ... | foreach {} act differently, I know there's a logical reason for it, in any case I've always got what I wanted out of foreach () {}

Comment: It was too long to post here (even with only 3 items in the list) so I put here: https://pastebin.com/Ts7040AA

If needed I can also post a screenshot of what it looks like in the table per view if that helps.